# QNetworkAccessManager multiple uploads fail

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

In my App, I have a method to upload files to the server, this works fine.

But when I call this method multiple times at once (like iterating over the result of a chooseFilesDialog) the first 7 (more or less) files are uploaded correctly, the others never get uploaded.

I think this has to be linked with the fact the server doesn't allow more than X connections from the same source maybe?

How can I make sure the upload waits for a free, established connection?

this is my method:

```
QString Api::FTPUpload(QString origin, QString destination)
{
    qint64 timestamp = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    QUrl url("ftp://ftp."+getLSPro("domain")+destination);
    url.setUserName(getLSPro("user"));
    url.setPassword(getLSPro("pwd"));

    QFile *data = new QFile(origin, this);
    if (data->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    {
        QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
        QNetworkReply *reply = nam->put(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
        reply->setObjectName(QString::number(timestamp));
        connect(reply, SIGNAL(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)), SLOT(uploadProgress(qint64, qint64)));

        return QString::number(timestamp);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not open file to FTP";
        return 0;
    }
}

void Api::uploadProgress(qint64 done, qint64 total) {
    QNetworkReply *reply = (QNetworkReply*)sender();
    emit broadCast("uploadProgress","{\"ref\":\""+reply->objectName()+"\" , \"done\":\""+QString::number(done)+"\", \"total\":\""+QString::number(total)+"\"}");
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new QNetworkAccessManager for each file you're uploading. This is not necessary; you only need one. Also, as you're not maintaining a pointer to the object, you'll be leaking memory too. Also note that QNetwork reply has a signal error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError code) that you should be handling to see what the actual problem is when uploads fail, rather than guessing that the problem is with the server's maximum connections.

Comment: Ok, I moved the QNetworkAccesManager outside and reuse the same, now uploads are performed one by one with a second or so between them. I assume QnetworkAccessManager has some kind of queue. Too bad there isn't some kind of multiple at once property. Thanks!
Not maintaining a pointer? where what object? (Im beginner with the concept of pointers)

Comment: Any time you use the keyword 'new', you should ensure that you maintain a pointer to it and call 'delete' when you've finished with it. In this case, the code you displayed created the QNetworkAccessManager called 'nam', which then goes out of scope. The object exists, but you have no pointer to call delete on when you no longer need the object, or when the program quits. The same rules apply to the QNetworkReply object 'reply', as it is a new object created and give to you by calling put().

Comment: Ok, got it, so now, my *nam, as being 'globally used' can remain as long as the app is running, but I delete the *reply. Thanks!

Comment: You should try to avoid global variables, if that's what you're doing. But either way, make sure it's deleted when the program quits, if not before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't create a QNetworkManager every time you start an upload.
Second, you definitely have to delete everything you `new()`, otherwise you are left with memory leaks. This includes the `QFile`, the `QNetworkManager` AND the `QNetworkReply` (!).
Third, you have to wait for the `finished()` signal.

```
Api::Api() {  //in the constructor create the network access manager
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager()
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finished(QNetworkReply*)));
}

Api::~Api() {  //in the destructor delete the allocated object
    delete nam;
}

bool Api::ftpUpload(QString origin, QString destination) {
    qint64 timestamp = QDateTime::currentMSecsSinceEpoch();
    QUrl url("ftp://ftp."+getLSPro("domain")+destination);
    url.setUserName(getLSPro("user"));
    url.setPassword(getLSPro("pwd"));

    //no allocation of the file object;
    //will automatically be destroyed when going out of scope
    //I use readAll() (see further) to fetch the data
    //this is OK, as long as the files are not too big
    //If they are, you should allocate the QFile object
    //and destroy it when the request is finished
    //So, you would need to implement some bookkeeping,
    //which I left out here for simplicity
    QFile file(origin);
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        QByteArray data = file.readAll();   //Okay, if your files are not too big
        nam->put(QNetworkRequest(url), data);
        return true;

        //the finished() signal will be emitted when this request is finished
        //now you can go on, and start another request
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
}

void Api::finished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    reply->deleteLater();  //important!!!!
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is clear. just to understand it correctly: in this scenario only, when the Api 'class' is instanciated once for the whole application's life, do I need to have a complete destructor? as the destructor will never be called.. (Or am I completely wrong?) When the App closes, does the OS clean up everything what remains?
I know it's best practice, but as I said, just to understand the OS behavior..

Comment: If the Api class is just a singleton, then you don't have to cleanup. It will be cleaned up when the application exits.  But, as you indicate, it is good practice to always cleanup the resources you allocate (or the files you open).  You never know, that on one day, you decide to dynamically create more than 1 object, then it is good to have cleanup code in place.